# Calling a function in Python - no class specified?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I noticed that some functions, for example `sorted`, can be called without specifying the instance they belong to - just like some function `f` I would define in my own class and won't need to specify that I'm calling them from my class.

Where do these functions belong and how does this hierarchy work?

Comment: Unlike object-oriented programming (like java), they do not belong to anything unless they are specified in a class

Comment: But how does python recognize them as legal function calls ? where are they written ?

Comment: Functions are like variables in python, not methods. This is called functional programming. Functions are of another type and can be called. Javascript is also like this. Python also has an object-oriented side to it, if you choose to use it, with classes. These functions are more like methods.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you would like it to behave. It is not clear to me from your description.

Comment: No, i think i misunderstood something. Now it's more clear - those are built-in functions of the interpreter that can be called anywhere, unlike functions i would define on my own.

Comment: You can define functions on your own and then import them wherever you need them (in other files). But sorted() doesn't need any import since it's in the stdlib

Answer (score 0):

In Python everything is an object. But you don't need to specify classes to everything. Some objects have their types (classes) hard-defined in the language core - that is the case for functions, integers, float, lists, dictionaries, strings and the like

So, whether you define a function inside a module or use a native function from some 3rd party package or from the builtins module, the function's type is "FunctionType" - which never needs to be declared explicitly.

And more related with your doubt: functions do not need to be related to any class - they are objects on their own, and the syntax of adding an optional list of arguments enclosed in mandatory parenthesis after their name calls them.

So just like C, Javascript, etc... you can create very complexes programs in Python with never defining a class.

Functions defined inside class bodies, on the other hand, are used as methods when retrieved through an instance of that class (or through the class if they are classmethods). That is Python 3 - Python 2 would be more complicated: functions defined inside a class body retrieved though the class itself are "unbound methods" - another object type.

And finally, the is a special module in Python called  `__builtins__`, which is populated by the Python runtime itself. Any name you try to use in a section of code is checked to be in one of these contexts: local context, nonlocal (outer closure for nested functions), global (variables, functions and classes defined at module level), or builtin (it is present in the `__builtins__` module).

There are a few functions and several classes defined in `__builtins__` which allow one to write fairly complete Python code without the need for any imports:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
```

So, what you type in a Python module is either a statement, one of the names above, or have to be declared prior to be used in some form (with an `=` statement, or though the use of `import`, or even a function with the `def` statement).

As a final advice, since you are learning Python you probably don't have a legacy codebase in Python 2 around there: you should be learning Python 3. It makes a lot of things simpler, and contains  more than 9 years of innovations  over Python 2, which will cease to be maintained 2 years from now.